# Create Structure JSON in Android/Java

Tags: java, android, json

I would like to do:

```
(Object)Date:
    (Object)HomeTeam:
        (Array)Name
        (Array)Num
    (Object)AwayTeam:
        (Array)Name
        (Array)Num
(Object)Date:
    (Object)HomeTeam:
        (Array)Name
        (Array)Num
    (Object)AwayTeam:
        (Array)Name
        (Array)Num
(Object)Date:
    (Object)HomeTeam:
        (Array)Name
        (Array)Num
    (Object)AwayTeam:
        (Array)Name
        (Array)Num
```

So far, I tried to:

```
JSONObject json = new JSONObject(); 
JSONObject home = new JSONObject();
JSONObject away = new JSONObject();
json.put("Date", xxx);  I dun know how to do
json.put("HomeTeam", home); 
json.put("AwayTeam", away);
```

And there are many date object, please help..

Comment: Use a better library; for instance, [Jackson](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-databind). Android's bundled JSON library is very limited -- it cannot even navigate JSON correctly, while Jackson's `JsonNode` navigates JSON much better than anything out there, and can {de,}serialize etc

Answer (score 0):

YOu can do this with bundled JSON lib. To get this struct:

```
(Object)Date:
    (Object)HomeTeam:
        (Array)Name
        (Array)Num
```

you do
    JSONObject date = new JSONObject();

```
JSONObject team = new JSONObject();
  team.put("Name", new JSONArray());
  team.put("Name", new JSONArray());
date.put("id", team);
```

Not that `"id"` should rather be different per node, or you should switch to JSONArray there.